# Black Screen issue on Samsung Note 5, Galaxy S7 Marshmallow on launching 2nd Activity of the application

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

We have received issues from Customers who are seeing Black screen on Samsung Note 5, Samsung Galaxy s7 after they updated their device to Marshmallow.  My application target SDK is 19. Basically the user are able to see the Launcher Activity A, but when they click on other activity B they see a Black screen.  Activity A--> singletask and Activity B has default launch mode.

We have tested this application on other Vendors Marshmallow( Motorola, Nexus) devices and it seems to be working well. We have also seen some customer using our application on Samsung Galaxy s7 Edge(Marshmallow) too.  We had one of the customer facing the same issue on Marshmallow Note 5, but he resolved that issue after Backing up the data from old Samsung J7 device, in which our application was running well. I am not sure, how backing up the data resolve this issue. Is there any device setting which is turned on or any thing which may be causing this issue. We do not have the Samsung Devices with Marshmallow and could not reproduce this issue.

Any advice appreciated, and let me know what could have caused this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We received ANR Logs from the users on Playstore and we found out the issue was due to the Spannable String which we had used. The issue seems to be on only Samsung Marshmallow (6.0) Devices. This issue has been fixed in Marshmallow 6.0.1. Really don't understand, why Android is customized to such extent by Samsung. As our application is running well on Motorola Marshmallow 6.0. Here is the entire Logs from Samsung Marshmallow. Hope this might help some one who is facing similar issue.

> ```
> at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1477)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1473)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1473)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1473)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1473)
>   ... repeated 3 times
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.calcMax(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1468)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.restoreInvariants(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1510)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:762)
>   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:662)
> ```

Additional Logs on other Samsung Galaxy Edge Marshmallow 6.0 devices related to Spannable Text View

```
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:857)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:864)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:844)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:864)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:864)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:864)
  ... repeated 7 times
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:844)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:864)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.countSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:844)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:823)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1053)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:763)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:662)
```